# "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" messages from Google

Tags: postfix, gmail, email-bounces

Some while back I set up a postfix server. I set the MX record for my domain name and sent a test message to one of my addresses on gmail.com. However, as the MX record change was not propagated by the time, the test mail bounced and I received a message from my postfix, containing the following:

> This is the mail system at host mypostfix.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
>   be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
>   delete your own text from the attached returned message.
>
> ```
>               The mail system
> ```
>
> : host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c00::1a]
>       said: 550-5.7.1 [2a01:238:42e0:b900:831d:f7fa:815c:8d16] Our system has
>       detected that 550-5.7.1 this message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines
>       regarding PTR 550-5.7.1 records and authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1
>       https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ipv6_authentication_error for more 550
>       5.7.1 information. y5si10216561eee.102 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA
>       command)
>
> Reporting-MTA: dns; xxx
>   X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 24665363A430
>   X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; xxx
>   Arrival-Date: Fri,  7 Feb 2014 21:00:20 +0100 (CET)
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; xxx@gmail.com
>   Action: failed
>   Status: 5.7.1
>   Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
>   Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [2a01:238:42e0:b900:831d:f7fa:815c:8d16] Our
>       system has detected that 550-5.7.1 this message does not meet IPv6 sending
>       guidelines regarding PTR 550-5.7.1 records and authentication. Please
>       review 550-5.7.1
>       https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ipv6_authentication_error for more 550
>       5.7.1 information. y5si10216561eee.102 - gsmtp

I receive this mail every hour and it's kind of freaking me out, as everything works as it should by now (I can send emails to gmail.com without any error).

Can I fix that somehow without telling my postfix to turn off notifications like these completely?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using IPv6 in your config ?  If so, you need to add a PTR record in your DNS configuration ([Reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup))

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your MX record. MX records designate where email is delivered TO for a particular domain, not where email is delivered FROM for a particular domain. You're sending email to a gmail.com email address, which is unrelated to your MX record.